# Not able to deploy SocialCustomerServiceSettings into scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I had retrieved my source code from a sandbox and converted the into source format using the mdapi:convert command. Now, I am trying to push the code into scratch org there is an error showing "**The object 'SocialCustomerServiceSettings' of type Settings metadata does not exist**".
I did some research to find the solution for this but not able to find anything related to it. I am not sure about whether I have to give another type of org configuration.

Here is my org definition.

```
{
    "orgName": "tarique Company",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "orgPreferences" : {
        "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled", "SocialProfilesEnable"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature setting and it can't be retrieved or deployed with metadata API.

Source : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm